# How to use Monad.Writer for tracing?

Tags: haskell, monads, trace

My code looks like this:

I would like to use tell inside the tokenize function in order to write to the same Writer Monad. Is this possible ?

```
tokenize :: T.Text -> T.Text -> [Token]
tokenize t token
   | T.null t = addToken token []
   | h == ' ' = addToken token (tokenize r "")
   | h == '"' = let (t', r') = consumeString r
                in addToken t' (tokenize r' "")
   | otherwise = tokenize r (T.snoc token h)
   where h = T.head t
         r = T.tail t

parse :: [T.Text] -> W.Writer String [Token]
parse lines = do
    let x = concatMap (\l -> tokenize l "") lines
    W.tell "hello"
    return x

main :: IO ()
main = do
    content <- readContent
    let lines = toTextList content
    let (res, log) = W.runWriter $ parse lines
    forM_ res $ \x ->
        print x
    print log
```

Comment: One option could be using `x <- concat <$> mapM (\l -> tokenize l "") lines` and rewriting `tokenize` in a monadic way. I'm not too happy with this because we lose the nice streaming performance of `concatMap`. I wonder if the monadic version can be made somehow to preserve streaming, knowing that we use the writer monad here...

Comment: @chi I hadn't thought of the performance implications. Would it help to defined a `concatMapM` as a fold?

Comment: @user2297560 I don't think an efficient `concatMapM` can exist while working on a generic monad. In the specific case of writer... I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to lift the result of `tokenize` into the `Writer`:

```
tokenize :: T.Text -> T.Text -> W.Writer [Token]
tokenize t token
   | T.null t = return $ addToken token []
   | h == ' ' = return $ addToken token (tokenize r "")
   | h == '"' = let (t', r') = consumeString r
                in return $ addToken t' (tokenize r' "")
   | otherwise = return $ tokenize r (T.snoc token h)
   where h = T.head t
         r = T.tail t
```

Then `parse` has to change to handle a monadic result from `tokenize`:

```
parse :: [T.Text] -> W.Writer String [Token]
parse lines = do
    x <- concat <$> mapM (\l -> tokenize l "") lines
    W.tell "hello"
    return x
```